# Koalas GroupBy > Apply > Lambda > Series

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, databricks, pandas-apply, spark-koalas

I am trying to port some code from Pandas to Koalas to take advantage of Spark's distributed processing. I am taking a dataframe and grouping it on A and B and then applying a series of functions to populate the columns of the new dataframe. Here is the code that I was using in Pandas:

```
new = old.groupby(['A', 'B']) \
  .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({
    'v1': x['v1'].sum(),
    'v2': x['v2'].sum(),
    'v3': (x['v1'].sum() / x['v2'].sum()),
    'v4': x['v4'].min()
    })
)
```

I believe that it is working well and the resulting dataframe appears to be correct value-wise.

I just have a few questions:

1. Does this error mean that my method will be deprecated in the future?
   `/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/group_ops.py:76: UserWarning: It is preferred to use 'applyInPandas' over this API. This API will be deprecated in the future releases. See SPARK-28264 for more details.`
2. How can I rename the group-by columns to 'A' and 'B' instead of `"__groupkey_0__   __groupkey_1__"?`
3. As you noticed, I had to call pd.Series -- is there a way to do this in Koalas? Calling ks.Series gives me the following error that I am unsure how to implement:
   `` PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead. ``

Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure about the error. I am using `koalas==1.2.0` and `pandas==1.0.5` and I don't get the error so I wouldn't worry about it
2. The `groupby` columns are already called `A` and `B` when I run the code. This again may have been a bug which has since been patched.
3. For this you have 3 options:

   1. Keep utilising `pd.Series`. As long as your original Dataframe is a `koalas` Dataframe, your output will also be a `koalas` Dataframe (with the `pd.Series` automatically converted to `ks.Series`)
   2. Keep the function and the data exactly the same and just convert the final dataframe to `koalas` using the `from_pandas` function
   3. Do the whole thing in `koalas`. This is slightly more tricky because you are computing an aggregate column based on two `GroupBy` columns and `koalas` doesn't support lambda functions as a valid aggregation. One way we can get around this is by computing the other aggregations together and adding the multi-column aggregation afterwards:

```py
import databricks.koalas as ks
ks.set_option('compute.ops_on_diff_frames', True)

# Dummy data
old = ks.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,1,2,3], "B":[1,2,3,3,2,3], "v1":[10,20,30,40,50,60], "v2":[4,5,6,7,8,9], "v4":[0,0,1,1,2,2]})

new = old.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'v1':'sum', 'v2':'sum', 'v4': 'min'})
new['v3'] = old.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda x: x['v1'].sum() / x['v2'].sum())
```